# How to customize link properties when creating ArangoSearchView in ArangoJS

Tags: node.js, arangodb, arangojs

I try to create an ArangoSearchView in arangojs, but I don't know how to set up view properties.
Here is my code:

```
const link = {
    includeAllFields: true,
    fields: { val: { analyzers: ["text_en"] } },
    storeValues: "val"
};
const view = _db.view(`${_viewName}`);
await view.create({ links: {mergeDB : link } });
```

However, I got this result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says the issue it's with the storeValue field

According the docs the value should be either `none` (default) or `id`

```
storeValues (optional; type: string; default: "none")

This property controls how the view should keep track of the attribute values. Valid values are:

none: Do not store value meta data in the View.
id: Store information about value presence to allow use of the EXISTS() function.

Not to be confused with storedValues, which stores attribute values in the View index.
```

Note that there is other parameter called `storedValues` but it's a top level field (same level as `links`)

Comment: Oh I forget that space could only be None or id. Thanks a lot:D